# Same CNAME balanced in 2 IPs

Tags: cloudflare

I have a domain balanced in 2 IPs:

```
A - domain.com - 1.1.1.1
A - domain.com - 2.2.2.2
```

but I want to convert the IPs on CNAMEs:

So, i've created 2 "A" entries:

```
A - master - 1.1.1.1
A - slave - 2.2.2.2
```

and I want to create 2 CNAMEs from root domain to another 2 servers in order to get working as load balancer:

```
CNAME - domain.com - master.domain.com
CNAME - domain.com - slave.domain.com
```

but Cloudflare **don't permitt create 2 same CNAMEs** although the domain target be different

How can I create an "domain.com" entry to get targeted to the 2 another load balance servers **by using CNAMEs**?

Answer (score 0):

I've created 2 "A" records:

```
A - balanced - 1.1.1.1
A - balanced - 2.2.2.2
```

and then link CNAME to "A"

```
CNAME - www - balanced.domain.com
```